# read LocalDate with bufferedreader - java

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I want read the following into `TimeEntry` with `BufferedReader`.

```
Date: 11.10.2016
start: 09:00
```

i know how to convert `String` to `LocalDate`, but i have no idea how to use it in my code with `BufferedReader`

I guess i need this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
    " * Date:*(\\\d\\\ d)\\\ .(\\\d\\\d)\\\ .(\\\d\\\d\\\d\\\d) *"
);
```

---

```
public class TimeEntry {
    private LocalDate date;
    private LocalTime start;

    public TimeEntry(LocalDate date, LocalTime start) {
        this.date = date;
        this.start = start;
    }
```

---

```
try {
    File file = new File("MailDaten.txt");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;
    String[] line_split = line.split(" ");
    String test = line_split[0];
     int  s = test.split("@")[0].lastIndexOf(" ");
    String name = test.substring(0,s);
    String mail = test.substring(s+1,test.length());

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        line_split = line.split(" ");
        Daten.add(
            new MailEntry(
                name, mail, 
                new TimeEntry(
                    line_split[3], line_split[3], line_split[4], line_split[5]
                )
            )
        );

        stringBuffer.append(line);
        stringBuffer.append("\n");
    }
    fileReader.close();
    System.out.println("Contents of file:");
    System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
String input = "Date: 11.10.2016\r\n" +
               "start: 09:00\r\n";
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(input))) {
    String dateLine = in.readLine();
    String startLine = in.readLine();

    if (! dateLine.matches("Date: \\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}"))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid date line: " + dateLine);
    if (! startLine.matches("start: \\d{2}:\\d{2}"))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid start line: " + startLine);

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateLine.substring(6), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu"));
    LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse(startLine.substring(7), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));

    LocalDateTime dateStart = LocalDateTime.of(date, start);
    System.out.println(dateStart); // prints: 2016-10-11T09:00
}
```

Comment: You should avoid calling `String#matches(regex)` in a loop as it will recompile the regex at each call which is costly

Comment: @NicolasFilotto True. For the same reason, the code shouldn't create the `DateTimeFormatter` objects inside the loop. --- Oh wait. My code doesn't *have* a loop.

Comment: ah yes that's right, it is so uncommon to use `BufferedReader` without a stream or a loop that I missed that my bad

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I agree, `BufferedReader` implies *loop*. I had written the comment to you and was ready to press Enter when I realized there was no loop. I *wrote* the code, and it took *me* that long. ;-)